# How to Add Quick Icon to be Published Custom Component for Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, icons, controls, components, panel

I am building a custom Joomla component and I would like a Quick Icon to be published to the user’s control panel when they install it.  I found a tutorial here:

`http://www.mindpalette.com/custom-admin-quickicon-in-joomla-2-5/`

But the problem here is that it is installed as a separate plugin which then has to be manually published by the user.  I know that components like Kunena and Mobile Joomla have this feature available, but without hacking into their methods I was hoping that someone could give me a tip on the process.

Answer (score 0):

Just build a package containing the component and the plugin.

The plugin can have a post install hook where you publish the plugin. Or you could offer such option from the component's main window as [LittleHelper](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-desk/24016) does.